# How to reset all default styles of the HTML5 button element

Tags: css, html, button, default, user-agent

### Scenario

I use the `<button>` element which appeares just as plain text with an "+" on right end.

On click a div element expands and reveals some information. I think the button element is semanticaley correct to represent such a ... button ... trigger.

### Problem

So I have mixed some buttons and h2 elements and I have got a visual problem. After resetting all **default user agent style's** I expect that every element I introduce to the document looks plain and unstyled.

But the button element does not look that plain. It has an text, slightly, text indention.

### Example

[image: First, three elements are <h2><button>TEXT</button></h2> and the two from above are just <h2>TEXT</h2>]

First, three elements are `<h2><button>text node</button></h2>` and the two from above are just `<h2>text node</h2>`

### CSS

```
* {
        /*Reset's every elements apperance*/
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
        border: medium none;
        border-spacing: 0;
        color: #26589F;
        font-family: 'PT Sans Narrow',sans-serif;
        font-size: 16px;
        font-weight: normal;
        line-height: 1.42rem;
        list-style: none outside none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        text-align: left;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-indent: 0;
}
```

### Other element's CSS

The other elements use background-image, text-transform:uppercase and that's it. In Firebug there are **no** paddings,margins,text-indents or other "soft" or "hard" properties which could mess things up. I played around with display settings but it does not "fix" anything or make it worse.

### Question

Can anybody explain why, even after resetting the default styles, there is this visual failure on the `<button>` element?

Comment: I found that `button { all: unset; }` copied from fregante's [comment](https://gist.github.com/MoOx/9137295?permalink_comment_id=4297342#gistcomment-4297342) to a gist worked well for me

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
button::-moz-focus-inner,
input::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

add this one also in css it will solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you very much. I don't know why this even works in Safari... even if it's -moz. But okay... i just go with.

Comment: one more: background: transparent