# Why would the same browser render two buttons with the same CSS differently?

Tags: css, rendering

I need button which has more bling than a standard browser rendering, and because I am not a designer, I thought I'd use an existing solution. So, I went to [a button maker](http://css-tricks.com/examples/ButtonMaker/#) I found on the Internet, and it made me a button which looks good. I copied the CSS, and my own button looks differently in my browser. On Inspect Element, the CSS is the same.

Their button looks like this:

[image]

And it has following rules applied:

[image]

My button looks uglier, because it gets a large border on all sides:

[image]

But when I look at the CSS, there is no difference to the applied rules. And while my element is an `input`, I also have "real" buttons on my page, and they show the same behavior.

[image]

I tried running my page with or without a resetting CSS, but this made no difference. I always get the ugly look.

When I run their code in a fiddle, I [get the same ugly result](http://jsfiddle.net/v77Kf/).

This happens in two different tabs of the same browser on the same machine, a Firefox 29.

Here again the problematic code:

```
button {
   border-top: 1px solid #bfd1ed;
   background: #5987d1;
   background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#2662c3), to(#5987d1));
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #2662c3, #5987d1);
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #2662c3, #5987d1);
   background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #2662c3, #5987d1);
   background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #2662c3, #5987d1);
   padding: 5px 10px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
   -moz-border-radius: 8px;
   border-radius: 8px;
   -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
   -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
   box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
   text-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,.4) 0 1px 0;
   color: #ffffff;
   font-size: 14px;
   font-family: Georgia, serif;
   text-decoration: none;
   vertical-align: middle;
   }
button:hover {
   border-top-color: #2662c3;
   background: #2662c3;
   color: #bdbdbd;
   }
button:active {
   border-top-color: #2662c3;
   background: #2662c3;
   }

body {
    background-color: #555555;
}
```

Comment: You should check the computed section, there you will find differences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put `border: none;` on your button:

http://jsfiddle.net/wn7vh/

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the edit! I opened the link under your old fiddle and was disappointed, didn't even notice that it is the wrong link!

Answer (score 5):

The difference is you're using a `button` element.

Us a `span` element and you'll get the same result.

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/dWKSK/)

You might also take the opposite approach and try to [reset the button's style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16077341/how-to-reset-all-default-styles-of-the-html5-button-element) but in my opinion it's easier to style a span than to remove those styles.

Comment: Well, this does look good, but I can't bind a javascript or submit a form with these. My elements have to remain buttons and inputs, there is lots of functionality which depends on it.

Comment: You can't *"bind a javascript or submit a form with these"* ? Of course you can...

Comment: But if you really want to use `button` elements, then follow the link I gave, the question has some nice css related to resetting the button style.

Comment: I am not the person who is doing the binding, but the dev who does it said he can't, unless he uses some kind of framework, which we don't want in these places. The decision to use button elements is more important to us than styling, because lots of our logic depends on it, and even if it can be rebuilt with spans, it is probably not worth it for us.

Comment: It turns out that EyeSpy's simple idea works very well indeed. Else I would have probably tried the reset from your link. Do you know if the reset is cross-browser compatible? I can't find info on it, and just as the OP in the other question, the moz prefix seems suspicious.

Comment: the interesting part in the link I gave is the question, not the answer.

Comment: Just in case anyone lands here in 2019+ and hasn't heard: please don't use `span` for a button, it's terrible for accessibility.

Answer (score 1):

Thats because you use the wrong HTML tag

the css in your example is for an element with the class "button"

and if you look at the example in the button builder, you will see that they don't use:

```
<button name="My button"> A button! </button>
```

but they use a link tag and style it like a button:

```
<a class="button" name="My button" href="#">A button!</a>
```

so if you use the second version for the button, it will look like the example in the button builder